# embeds_many with condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How can I do an `embeds_many` if a field is of a specific value? For example. Lets assume a member of the family can have one or many cars `if` they are older than or equal to 18 years of age.

```
class FamilyMember
  include Mongoid::Document

  # Psuedo code
  embeds_many :cars, :if :age >= 18

  field :member_type, :type => String # can be dad, mom, son, daughter
  field :age, :type => Integer
end
```

Is such a thing possible or would I have to go through some other means. i.e. validation?

Answer (score 2):

try this and take a look [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) for more information

```
embeds_many :cars do
    def with_age(age=18)
      where(age: age)
    end
end
```

then you have to use, something like this `family_member.cars.with_age(18)` or `family_member.cars.with_age`, and then you can modify condition as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

In active record you could do

```
has_many :cars, :conditions => ['age >= ?', 18]
```

I have not tried it in mongoid though.

Answer (score 0):

```
embeds_many :cars, :if => :check_age

def check_age
  return true if self.age >= 18
end
```